# clientidmode is unexpectedly prefixed in request.form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm dynamically creating controls and assigning the id.

When I parse through the request, the assigned key is there, but it is prefixed by all the controls the dynamically created control is created in.

How can I ensure that the request[key] is the same as the id I assigned?

for example

request["mykey"]

instead of

request["ctl01$ctl02$mykey"]

Comment: Why do you need to access  [`Request.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx)  anyway? Note: You cannot ensure that the name of a control is the same as the ID. Otherwise you need to use HTML-Controls instead of server-controls-

Comment: Here you'll find more(also look at the comments): http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40

Answer (score 0):

request.form uses client side names not ids.

the ids were correctly set using clientidmode='static'

there is currently no way of assigning the name to asp.net web controls.

i think i could get this to work using html controls with runat=server, but i've decided to just use the ugly keys to parse my request.form.